# How do I convert the x and y values in polar form from these coupled ODEs to to cartesian form and graph them?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing, polar-coordinates

I have written this code to model the motion of a spring pendulum

```html
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def deriv(z, t):
    
    x, y, dxdt, dydt = z

    dx2dt2=(0.415+x)*(dydt)**2-50/1.006*x+9.81*cos(y)
    dy2dt2=(-9.81*1.006*sin(y)-2*(dxdt)*(dydt))/(0.415+x)
    
    return np.array([x,y, dx2dt2, dy2dt2])

init = array([0,pi/18,0,0])
time = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
sol = odeint(deriv,init,time)

def plot(h,t):
    n,u,x,y=h
    n=(0.4+x)*sin(y)
    u=(0.4+x)*cos(y)
    return np.array([n,u,x,y])

init2 = array([0.069459271,0.393923101,0,pi/18])

time2 = np.linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
sol2 = odeint(plot,init2,time2)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.plot(sol2[:,0], sol2[:, 1], label = 'hi')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

where x and y are two variables, and I'm trying to convert x and y to the polar coordinates n (x-axis) and u (y-axis) and then graph n and u on a graph where n is on the x-axis and u is on the y-axis. However, when I graph the code above it gives me:

[image]

Instead, I should be getting an image somewhat similar to this:
[image]

The first part of the code - from "def deriv(z,t): to sol:odeint(deriv..." is where the values of x and y are generated, and using that I can then turn them into rectangular coordinates and graph them. How do I change my code to do this? I'm new to Python, so I might not understand some of the terminology. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution should give you the expected result, but there is a mistake in the implementation of the ode.

The function you pass to odeint should return an array containing the solutions of a *1st*-order differential equations system.

In your case what you are solving is

[image]

While instead you should be solving

[image]

In order to do so change your code to this

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def deriv(z, t):

    x, y, dxdt, dydt = z

    dx2dt2 = (0.415 + x) * (dydt)**2 - 50 / 1.006 * x + 9.81 * cos(y)
    dy2dt2 = (-9.81 * 1.006 * sin(y) - 2 * (dxdt) * (dydt)) / (0.415 + x)

    return np.array([dxdt, dydt, dx2dt2, dy2dt2])


init = array([0, pi / 18, 0, 0])
time = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 1000)
sol = odeint(deriv, init, time)

plt.plot(sol[:, 0], sol[:, 1], label='hi')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The second part of the code looks like you are trying to do a change of coordinate.
I'm not sure why you try to solve the ode again instead of just doing this.

```
x = sol[:,0]
y = sol[:,1]

def plot(h):
    x, y = h
    n = (0.4 + x) * sin(y)
    u = (0.4 + x) * cos(y)
    return np.array([n, u])

n,u = plot( (x,y))
```

As of now, what you are doing there is solving this system:

[image]

Which leads to x=e^t and y=e^t  and n' = (0.4 + e^t) * sin(e^t)   u' = (0.4 + e^t) * cos(e^t).

Without going too much into the details, with some intuition you could see that this will lead to an attractor as the derivative of *n* and *u* will start to switch sign faster and with greater magnitude at an exponential rate, leading to *n* and *u* collapsing onto an attractor as shown by your plot.

If you are actually trying to solve another differential equation I would need to see it in order to help you further

This is what happen if you do the transformation and set the time to 1000:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My code works - but now I'm curious as to why I actually get a graph that looks like that. I am trying to track the x-y coordinates of a spring pendulum over time but the graphs I'm getting aren't symmetrical about the y-axis, which I would expect to to be the case for the motion of a pendulum. Have I done something wrong, or is this really the path that the mass would take? My equations of motion are the equations with dx2dt2 and dy2dt2 in them. (Apologies if this question isn't allowed because it isn't specifically related to the original question). Thank you again!!

Comment: I think it depends on the starting condition and the fact that you didn't give enough time to the ode to do a 'full loop' in order to get back to your original starting condition. If i set the time to 1000 it seems to me that you get a symmetric shape for the second plot (where I think you are converting the radial solution from the first part where x=radius and y=angle to the actual cartesian coordinates).

Comment: @Charlotte Noxon Also please 'accept' and 'upvote' if the solution worked for you :)

Comment: Will do :) Sorry, I'm quite new to stack overflow. Even when I set time to 1000, it gives me a graph that is symmetrical about the x-axis whereas I want one symmetrical about the y-axis (i.e. something like the graphs in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_pendulum). I feel like I have maybe switched the x- and y-axes up in my code or something similar??

Comment: Have you tried using the second part of the code to transform the coordinates? I will add a figure to the answer